# Is voting a form of rent seeking?

Tags: voting

Do all voting a form of rent seeking?

For example, say a group of voters vote for tariff free removal. Another wants to protect steel industry.

Are both doing rent seeking?

It seems that removal of tariff create wealth while protection undo wealth.

Am I correct here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Rent-seeking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rent-seeking) is a motive, voting is an act.

Rent-seeking *can* be a motive to vote in a specific way. For example when one says "I vote for whoever proposes a taxation scheme in which I pay the least taxes and a budget in which I am entitled to the most subsidies". But not everyone bases their voting decision solely on their own economic interests.